# PopUp window not able to click on OK button which Is under Modal window class - Selenium [JAVA]

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, modal-dialog, sendkeys

**a popup** that displayed while tried to change some data. that stored on **Modal Dialog window**

tried many times to click on [OK] but its not interact with element.

First within Click().
and then within Send Keys and its not worked..

```html
div class="modal show" id="myModal-vechail" aria-modal="true" style="padding-right: 17px; display: block;">
    <div class="modal-body bg-white">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 pt-2">You have changed vehicle model. Would you like to proceed?</div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row pt-3 pb-2 justify-content-center">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="model-confirmed" tabindex="null" class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary btn-lg mr-md-3 step-control">Ok</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="changeModelPopupCancel" tabindex="null" class="col-md-3  btn btn-primary btn-lg step-control" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the source Code **[ it is print the Body Text But not clicking on Ok button plus the Enter Key]**:

```
String s1= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='myModal-vechail']/div/div/div[1]")).getText();
System.out.println(s1);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
Thread.sleep(2000);
 
//driver.findElement(By.id("model-confirmed")).click();
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.sendKeys(Keys.TAB ).perform();
act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: What happens when you do `//driver.findElement(By.id("model-confirmed")).click();` ?

Comment: it display an Error Message as "  not interact with an element " @cruisepandey

Comment: is it ElementNotInteractable ?

Comment: its like [    org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id='model-confirmed'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)  ] @cruisepandey

Comment: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Ok'and @id='model-confirmed']")).click();` try this and let me know

Comment: i Fix it By using [  act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();   ] .. thanks for helping @cruisepandey

Comment: @cruisepandey find the above dear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED BY USING ".perform()"

```
act.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with **linkText** as well.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Ok"))).click();
```

or with xpath :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Ok'and @id='model-confirmed']"))).click();
```

Comment: tried before unfortunately , it display an Error Message[     org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Ok"}    ]   @cruisepandey

Comment: @Malikah : is your windows maximized when you launched it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='myModal-vechail']//*[contains(text(),'Ok')]"))).click();
```

Comment: even though tried on this from before which is have an Error Message [    org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id='model-confirmed'] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)     ]  @Prophet

Comment: need to see the web page to give the correct locator